# Why the prior distribution can be neglected compared with likelihood function in the posterior distribution when sample is large

Tags: bayesian

Here is the theorem, `Bayesian posterior estimation is same as MLE under the large samples` and its prove in the book `All of Statistics A Concise Course in Statistical Inference page 190`. However I cannot understand why:

1. $f(\theta|X^n)\approx \mathcal{L}_n(\theta)$ when $n\rightarrow\infty.$
2. $\dfrac{1}{n}\sum-\mathcal{l}''_i(\hat{\theta}_n)\approx\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[-\mathcal{l}''_i(\hat{\theta}_n)].$ I already known this is from the CLT.

Can any one give me more detail of prove?

[image]

[image]
I am so confused for the last two steps

First, do we regard $\mathcal{l}''_i(\hat{\theta}_n)$ as a constant independent of $\theta,$ then we have $\mathcal{l}''_i(\hat{\theta}_n) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}[\mathcal{l}''_i(\hat{\theta}_n)]?$

Second, even though, $I(\hat{\theta}_n) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}[\mathcal{l}''_i(\theta_n)]\Big|_{\theta_n = \hat{\theta}_n}\neq\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[\mathcal{l}''_i(\hat{\theta}_n)].$